# C++ higher order functions: different results when declaring multiple functions

Tags: c++, lambda

I was plying with higher order functions, and I started getting different results when I created two instances and assigning them to variables.

I reduced the issue to the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

using ColorGetter = int(*)(void);

auto paint(const ColorGetter &f)
{
    return [&]() { return f(); };
}

int colorA() { return 10; }

int colorB() { return 20; }

int main()
{
    auto painter1 = paint(colorA);
    auto painter2 = paint(colorB);
    std::cout << "painter 1 : " << painter1() << "\n";
    std::cout << "painter 2 : " << painter2() << "\n";

    auto p1 = [] () { return colorA(); };
    auto p2 = [] () { return colorB(); };
    std::cout << "p 1 : " << p1() << "\n";
    std::cout << "p 2 : " << p2() << "\n";
}
```

My expectation was to get 10, followed by 20 from both sequences.
Instead, depending on the compiler, I get:

```
➜  tmp clang++-13 -o out.gcc wrong.cpp&& ./out.gcc       
painter 1 : 10
painter 2 : 20
p 1 : 10
p 2 : 20
➜  tmp g++-11 -o out.gcc wrong.cpp && ./out.gcc
painter 1 : 20
painter 2 : 20
p 1 : 10
p 2 : 20
```

Is there something fundamentally wrong with the above code?
I get no compiler warnings or clang-tidy issues, at least with my current settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at this code:

```
auto paint(const ColorGetter &f)
{
    return [&]() { return f(); };
}
```

The `f` parameter only exists for the lifetime of the function `paint`. Your lambda function captures it by reference (that's the `[&]` bit), and so your lambda capture is referencing a variable (the reference `f`) that no longer exists after the function ends. As a result, the object you're returning holds a dangling reference to the function. You're seeing undefined behavior here, which is why the result varies across compilers.

To fix this, change the code to read

```
auto paint(const ColorGetter &f)
{
    return [=]() { return f(); };
}
```

This will cause the lambda capture to make a copy of the value stored in `f` (the pointer to the function in question), which will outlive the `paint` function.

Comment: D'oh! Thank you! Goes to show I should think more about the captures instead of blindly putting [&] on everything.

Comment: @MarcinBlazejewski That's right.  Capture by reference is full of pitfalls like this.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't keeping track of lifetime.

```
auto paint(const ColorGetter &f)
{
  return [&]() { return f(); };
}
```

this captures a reference to `f`.  You should almost NEVER use `[&]` when the lambda outlives the scope it is created in.

The `f` is:

```
auto painter1 = paint(colorA);
```

a temporary pointer created on this line.  It is discarded at the end of the statement.

So your code, when it does `f()`, exhibits undefined behavior -- you are following a dangling reference.

The easy fixes include:

```
auto paint(const ColorGetter &f)
{
  return [=]() { return f(); };
}
```

I would also get rid of the reference-to-pointer:

```
auto paint(const ColorGetter f)
{
  return [=]() { return f(); };
}
```

while I am at it.  Taking `const&` to arguments blindly is a bad habit.  As is taking things by value blindly.  Know what you are passing.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the case. I'll take a look at removing the const ref. Clang-tidy usually complains with performance-unnecessary-value-param if I don't use a ref, but that's no reason to follow it blindly.

Comment: @MarcinBlazejewski clang-tidy is wrong.  Passing a 64 bit pointer is cheaper than passing a const reference to such a pointer at runtime, and makes the program harder to reason about.